# R: disjoint complex number when setting function body

Tags: r, function

While constructing a function I discovered, that complex numbers are disjoint when setting the function body:

```
funCplx <- function () {}
formals(funCplx) <- alist(t=)
body(funCplx) <- as.call(c(as.name("{"), parse(text = "t*(2+3i)")))
funCplx
funCplx(3)
```

As you can see, the function returns the correct value, but contains `t * (2+(0+3i))`. It is disjoint within the `c()`. The expression `c(parse(text = "t*(2+3i)"))` returns the disjoint term, whereas `parse(text = "t*(2+3i)")` returns `t*(2+3i)`.
Why is the expression disjoint in the body?

Edit: I add an argument to the function. I removed it for sparseness, but it gets necessary to get the correct solution.

Edit 2: Most answers assume I know the complex number (here `2+3i`). I took this example, because it is minimal.
In my real case, I take many complex numbers from variable matrices and put them together in one function with additional variables (here `t`) and functions like `exp`. In my first step I `paste` different parts and `parse` this text into the function body.

**To point out my question:** Is it bad that the complex number is disjoint in the `parse` function in case of calculation steps? Reworded: Does R need more calculation steps to calculate `5*(2+(0+3i))` than `5*(2+3i)`?

Comment: The R parser parses `2 + 3i` as the real number `2` + the imaginary number `0 + 3i`. You can see this if you run `deparse(parse(text = "2+3i"))`

Comment: Thank you! So the function body is correct and it does not need more time to compute `2+3i` than `2+(0+3i)`.

Comment: Actually, `parse(...)` and `c(parse(...))` are identical, they only *print* differently because the first one has a `srcref` attribute which keeps the string you entered in the console. In both cases you're not putting a complex number inside the function body, but a call to the `+` function, and two arguments (`2` and `0+3i`). Check this by typing `parse(text = "2+3i")[[1]]`

Comment: What you are discovering is that expressions get parsed, and that complex numbers are parsed (and stored) as real + (0+complex).

Comment: @DWin, I don't think they are "stored" as "real + (0+complex)". The problem here is that `parse` transforms the string "2+3i" into a call, not a complex constant. Compare `is(parse(text="2+3i")[[1]])` and `is(parse(text="3i")[[1]])`.

Comment: From ?complex: "Internally, complex numbers are stored as a pair of double precision numbers, ...". So perhaps not as a text version of "real+(0+complex), definitely something with a real and complex component.

Comment: R can parse a string representing a complex number *directly* into a vector of type `complex` *only if* it's purely imaginary. The problem here is the "+" sign, which invariably parses as a call to the `'+'` function. Note that the same aplies to `"0+3i"`. If you want to build a complex from the values stored in two numeric variables, you can use the first answer I gave you, and you said wasn't your "goal"...

Comment: The complex numbers are a resulting vector from a previous applications. These values are `paste`ed in a new function. To use your answer, I have to extract the real and imaginary part from my first vector. Hence, I said it was not my goal.

Answer (score 2):

Why not:

```
funCplx <- function () {}
formals(funCplx) <- alist()
body( funCplx) <- as.call(c(as.name("{"), eval(parse(text = "2+3i"))) )
funCplx
funCplx()
```

Returns:

```
funCplx
#----console displays---
function () 
{
    2+3i
}
```

With the added request to include extra arguments in what appears when the function is `print`-ed, you could make it look more "finished" by assigning the fixed value to a name and then using that name in the expression:

```
funCplx <- function () {}
formals(funCplx) <- alist(t=)
environment(funCplx) <- new.env()
environment(funCplx)$cplx <-  (2+3i)
body(funCplx) <- quote(t*cplx)
funCplx
# function (t) 
# t * cplx
funCplx(3)
# [1] 6+9i
```

And testing to see if the earlier flimsy construction error was fixed:

```
>  cplx=42
> funCplx(7)
[1] 14+21i
```

The earlier method didn't create an environment for funCplx and so its environment was .`GlobalEnv`. This version will carry 'cplx' around with it.

Comment: I need an argument in my function and missed this information in my question. This is not possible with `eval`. Sorry for that.

Comment: Your "goal" is not entirely clear. The functions in their various forms are returning what is desired.

Comment: caveat: `funCplx` depends on an external symbol: `cplx <- 6; funCplx(7)`.

Comment: Eww. My mistake. I thought `cplx` would get defined in the environment of the function. Will fix.

Comment: I learn from your answers, that I express my problem not very well. Please take a look at edit 2.

Answer (score 0):

To create an expression that multiplies an argument by a given complex constant, use this:

```
funCplx <- function () {}
formals(funCplx) <- alist(t=)
body(funCplx) <- as.call(c(as.name("{"), call("*", as.symbol("t"), 2+3i)))
funCplx
funCplx(3)
```

Note that this avoids evaluation of `2 + (0+3i)` at "run-time", since the constant is "hard-coded" in the function's body:

```
> body(funCplx)[[2]][[3]]
[1] 2+3i
> is(body(funCplx)[[2]][[3]])
[1] "complex" "vector"
```

Comment: That is not my goal. I add an argument to my function. Sorry for missing the argument at first.

Comment: I learn from your answer, that I express my problem not very well. Please take a look at edit 2.